# connection is not secure in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

When i am running  Asp.net Core App, it open Firefox web browser. But it will show this

> error massage "connection is not secure"

[image]

Comment: Does Firefox trust the CA that signed the certificate? Do you care? Why not just hit Advanced and bypass this warning if you trust the site?